# Ensure .csv file has same number of columns for each row in bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file in a Linux server that has multiple rows with a variance of fields. I would like to ensure that all records have the max number of columns (empty values) as the row with the max number of columns. I need to achieve this in a bash script. I would like to try to use awk if possible I am just new to bash.

Comment: How are your columns separated? `awk '{NF=5}1' file.txt` will split each row on spaces and print the first 5 columns. And you can use `-F ','` so set comma as the separater.

Comment: Yes they are separated by commas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue.
 You can do all in one script, using T.J.'s sample input file

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==FNR{if(max<NF)max=NF;next}; 
                           {NF=max}1' file{,} 
1,2,3,4,5,
1,2,3,4,,
1,2,3,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

**Explanation:** This is a double-pass algorithm, in the first round calculates the max and uses in the second. 
`NR==FNR` is true only for the first file, calculates the max, note that there is no need to initialize the max since default value is zero and the lengths will be non-negative. `next` skips the rest of the script.  In the second round setting `NF=max` fills up the records with fewer fields. `1` is used as a shorthand for print (or any true statement) based on `awk` defaults. Also `file{,}` resolves to `file file` for using the same file twice for the double-pass algorithm.

The same can be written with single-pass using arrays and END block as well.

Comment: whereis T.J.'s sample?

Comment: Bravo - best answer! Thank you for adding the explanation.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you! Great explanation as well. I am new to bash so it's great when someone explains what's going on, especially with awk!